# Already running application now gets socket error 10013

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I have an application done in VB.NET that listen on a specific UDP port and answer through the same port to the IP that send the packet.
It was working ok from a couple of years to the last month; now when try to answer crash due to socket error 10013.

I even try an older version that I know it was working too and get the same crash.

I try disabling Microsoft Security Essentials real time protection and Windows firewall and didn't work.

In the code I have the line

```
MyUdpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, True)
```

I have no clue about what to do, I'm lost.

Any idea how to solve this?

**Edit:**
Here's the code

```
#Region "UDP Send variables"
   Dim GLOIP As IPAddress
   Dim GLOINTPORT As Integer
   Dim bytCommand As Byte() = New Byte() {}
#End Region

Dim MyUdpClient As New UdpClient()

Private Sub StartUdpBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartUdpBtn.Click
      If StartUdpBtn.Tag = 0 Then
          '   If Not UdpOpen Then
          StartUdpReceiveThread(CInt(ListeningPortLbl.Text))
          'End If
      Else
          If ThreadReceive.IsAlive Then
              ThreadReceive.Abort()
              MyUdpClient.Close()
              PrintLog("UDP port closed")
              StartUdpBtn.Tag = 0
              UdpOpen = False
              StartUdpBtn.Text = "Start UDP"
          End If
      End If

      If UdpOpen Then
          StartUdpBtn.Tag = 1
          StartUdpBtn.Text = "Stop UDP"
      Else
          StartUdpBtn.Tag = 0
          StartUdpBtn.Text = "Start UDP"
          TimerUDP.Enabled = False
          TiempoUDP.Stop()
          TiempoUdpLbl.Text = "--:--:--"
      End If

  End Sub

Private Sub StartUdpReceiveThread(ByVal Port As Integer)
    Dim UdpAlreadyOpen As Boolean = False
    Try
        If Not UdpOpen Then
            MyUdpClient = New UdpClient(Port)
            MyUdpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, True)
            UdpAlreadyOpen = True
        Else
            Me.Invoke(Sub()
                          TiempoUDP.Restart()
                          If TimerUDP.Enabled = False Then
                              TimerUDP.Enabled = True
                          End If
                      End Sub)
        End If

        ThreadReceive = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf UdpReceive)
        ThreadReceive.IsBackground = True

        ThreadReceive.Start()
        UdpOpen = True

        If UdpAlreadyOpen Then 
                PrintLog(String.Format("UDP port {0} opened, waiting data...", Port.ToString))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        PrintErrorLog(ex.Message)
        PrintErrorLog(ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub UdpReceive()
    Dim receiveBytes As [Byte]() = MyUdpClient.Receive(RemoteIpEndPoint) 
    DstPort = RemoteIpEndPoint.Port
    IpRemota(RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString)
    Dim BitDet As BitArray
    BitDet = New BitArray(receiveBytes)
    Dim strReturnData As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes)
    If UdpOpen Then
        StartUdpReceiveThread(CInt(ListeningPortLbl.Text))
    End If

    PrintLog("From: " & RemoteIpLbl.Text & ":" & ListeningPortLbl.Text & " - " & strReturnData)
    AnswersProcessor(strReturnData)

End Sub

Private Sub UdpSend(ByVal txtMessage As String)
    Dim pRet As Integer
    GLOIP = IPAddress.Parse(RemoteIpLbl.Text)
    'From UDP_Server3_StackOv

    Using UdpSender As New System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient()
        Dim RemoteEndPoint = New System.Net.IPEndPoint(0, My.Settings.UDP_Port)
        UdpSender.ExclusiveAddressUse = False
        UdpSender.Client.SetSocketOption(Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel.Socket, Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, True)
        UdpSender.Client.Bind(RemoteEndPoint)
        UdpSender.Connect(GLOIP, DstPort)
        bytCommand = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtMessage)
        pRet = UdpSender.Send(bytCommand, bytCommand.Length)
    End Using

    PrintLog("No of bytes send " & pRet)
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show your actual code that is crashing. If the code was working before, and you haven't change the code since, then the problem has to be environmental.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added the code.

Comment: Based on @RemyLebeau's answer, it is possible that some other application is already using that port. You could try running
`netstat -a` from a command prompt or download TCPView from Microsoft. Check for something running on the same Port number you are trying to use.

Comment: @ElroySkimms No, there's no other application, I double checked by netstat and TCPView. When the application start nobody is using the port and when I start the server the application name appears in TCPView list because is listening all the incoming data from that specific port, when the data is received and processed all works ok, but when the application try to answer, an error is raised.

Comment: Remy's answer also mentions SocketOptionName.Broadcast [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname(v=vs.110).aspx) Is it possible that `MyUdpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, True)` is what you need?

Comment: @ElroySkimms No, I don't think so. As far I understand broadcast messages are for send data to many IP's on the same sub net, so you can send the data one time and being listen by all the sub net.

Comment: What is the Operating System? Are you running the application as administrator? [UdpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.exclusiveaddressuse(v=vs.110).aspx) Try `MyUdpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = False` before calling 'SetSocketOption'

Comment: @ElroySkimms Windows 7 x64. I'm not running at this time as administrator but I tried and didn't work, raises the same error. I added the line for ExclusiveAddressUse =false and get the same error. Also I tried to disable the line UdpSender.Client.Bind(RemoteEndPoint) by commenting it and works ok but just for one packet, the next packet sent by the remote endpoint is ignored.

Comment: I tried the program on a XP x32 and works ok but on Windows 7 x32/x64 don't, even if I disable the firewall and Microsoft Security Essentials Live Protection.

Answer (score 2):

10013 is `WSAEACCES`, which is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668.aspx) as follows:

> Permission denied.
>
> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. An example is using a broadcast address for sendto without broadcast permission being set using setsockopt(SO_BROADCAST).
>
> Another possible reason for the WSAEACCES error is that when the bind function is called (on Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later), another application, service, or kernel mode driver is bound to the same address with exclusive access. Such exclusive access is a new feature of Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later, and is implemented by using the SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE option.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you mentioned:

> I tried the program on a XP x32 and works ok but on Windows 7 x32/x64 don't, even if I disable the firewall and Microsoft Security Essentials Live Protection.

Maybe it sounds almost obvious but you could try to start your program in all of the available *Windows XP compatibility modes*. You didn't say that you already tried this but maybe you're lucky and the problem will be "solved" by this workaround.

If the problem still exists afterwards and considering the error code of 10013, I would try or check the following things:

- I know you disabled "Microsoft Security Essentials" and the Windows Firewall, but *double check* whether there are other security related programs/services like anti virus protection, anti malware tools etc. running. It really sounds like something is blocking your socket creation/bind.
- In case your program created log output/data which allows you to see exactly *when* it started to fail:

  - Any new software installed at that time?
  - Were Windows Updates (maybe automatically) installed at that time? Especially security updates regarding network security?
  - Any other noticeable changes in your environment? What about log entries in your Windows system log?

---

- Just as a little test to verify if the error occurs only with your UDP socket: Try to use a TCP socket instead of UDP.
- Start the machine in Windows *Safe Mode with network support* and execute your program from there.
- Run your program on another Windows 7 machine and see if the same problem occurs there. It could be a valuable starting point (in terms of localization) to know if the problem occurs only on specific versions of Windows.
- Single step through your code with a debugger and carefully watch what happens. Perhaps this can reveal some additional info on what's going wrong.

Maybe some of the ideas above can help you to track down the problem a little bit more. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I tried on XP SP2 and SP3 compatibility mode, also with Admin rights in both compatibility modes too. I don't have any other tools and I tried on another two PC's with same results. The LOG says that the data is being received but crash when try to answer to the remote host; specifically when the UdpSend subroutine try to execute the line UdpSender.Client.Bind(RemoteEndPoint). The whole idea is to wait some data from a remote GPRS modem and answer if its needed and send commands to the last remote IP that sent any data. The remote IP, since is GPRS, is not always the same.