# What's the difference between this two Close methods?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, udp, vb.net-2010

If I have the following code

```
Dim MyUdpClient As New UdpClient()
MyUdpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = False
MyUdpClient = New UdpClient(Port)
MyUdpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, True)
Dim receiveBytes As [Byte]() = MyUdpClient.Receive(RemoteIpEndPoint)
```

What's the difference between the following two lines?

```
MyUdpClient.Client.Close()
MyUdpClient.Close()
```

I have not clear that.

Comment: `UdpClient.Client` is the underlying socket which the `UdpClient` uses to communicate. *In this particular case*, there isn't much difference between either `Close()` statement. With that said, the more proper thing to do would be to use `UdpClient.Close()`, as it expects to own, and clean up after, the underlying socket. In general, when a disposable object is a property or field of another object, the "outer" object is responsible for taking care of disposing the "inner" ones.

Comment: There is no difference.  UdpClient is a friendly little helper class that avoids anybody from having to plow through the dense Socket class documentation.  It still has a if-you-really-have-to backdoor through the Client property.  You don't have to.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot There's another case where is not the same thing call one method or the other? I'm trying to make a little UDP Server but I can't make work on Win 7, it works only on Win XP. Please check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492047/already-running-application-now-gets-socket-error-10013